# The density of simple functions in the intersection of mixed norm spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

**Problem 1.**
Let
$\mathcal{A}([0,1] \times [0,1])$
be the set of all measurable functions
$f:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$
that satisfy the conditions
$$
\alpha_1(f)
=
\operatorname*{ess sup}_{y \in [0,1]}
\int\limits_{0}^{1}
\lvert f(x,y) \rvert \,
dx
< \infty,
$$
$$
\alpha_2(f)
=
\operatorname*{ess sup}_{x \in [0,1]}
\int\limits_{0}^{1}
\lvert f(x,y) \rvert \,
dy
<\infty.
$$
One can prove that
$\mathcal{A}([0,1] \times [0,1])$
is a Banach space with the norm
$$
\lVert f \rVert_{\mathcal{A}([0,1] \times [0,1])}
=
\max \bigl(\alpha_{1}(f), \alpha_{2}(f) \bigr).
$$

**Question 1.**
Consider the set
$\Phi([0,1] \times [0,1])$
of a simple functions of the form
$$
\phi(x,y)
=
\sum_{i=1}^{N}
\lambda_i \, \chi_{E_i}(x,y),
$$
where
$\lambda_1, \ldots \lambda_N, \in \mathbb{C}$
is a sequence of complex numbers,
$E_1, \ldots, E_N$
is a sequence of disjoint measurable subsets of a set
$[0,1] \times [0,1]$,
$\chi_{E_i}$
is the indicator function of the set $E_i$.
Is
$\Phi([0,1] \times [0,1])$
**dense** in
$\mathcal{A}([0,1] \times [0,1])$?

**Question 2.**
Consider the set
$\Psi([0,1] \times [0,1])$
of a simple functions of the form
$$
\psi(x,y)
=
\sum_{i=1}^{N}
\lambda_i \, \chi_{X_i}(x) \, \chi_{Y_i}(y),
$$
where
$X_1, \ldots, X_N$
and
$Y_1, \ldots, Y_N$
are sequences of disjoint measurable subsets of a set
$[0,1]$.
Is
$\Psi([0,1] \times [0,1])$
**dense** in
$\mathcal{A}([0,1] \times [0,1])$?

**Problem 2.**
Let
$\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$
be the set of all measurable functions
$f:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$
that satisfy the conditions
$$
\alpha_1(f) 
=
\operatorname*{ess sup}_{y \in \mathbb{R}}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\lvert f(x,y) \rvert \,
dx
< \infty,
$$
$$
\alpha_2(f)
=
\operatorname*{ess sup}_{x \in \mathbb{R}}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\lvert f(x,y) \rvert \,
dy
<\infty.
$$

It is not hard to show that
$\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$
is a Banach space with the norm
\begin{equation}
\lVert f \rVert_{\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})}
=
\max \bigl(\alpha_{1}(f), \alpha_{2}(f) \bigr).
\end{equation}

**Question 3.**
Similar to questions 1 and 2:
are
$\Phi(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$
and
$\Psi(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$
dense in
$\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$?

As I can figure it out, simple functions are not dense in the Banach space of functions
$f:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$
that satisfy the condition
$\alpha_1(f) < \infty$ only.
(See A. Benedek, R. Panzone. The spaces $L^p$ with mixed norm, Duke Mathematical Journal, Volume 28, issue 3, 1961, p. 308),
but I failed to understand why.
And what about the space $\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$?

**My attempt to answer question 1.**
Let $E \subset [0,1] \times [0,1]$, and define
\begin{equation*}
E^x = \{y \in [0,1]:\: (x,y) \in E \},
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
E^y = \{x \in [0,1]:\: (x,y) \in E \}.
\end{equation*}
Since for any
$\phi \in \Phi([0,1] \times [0,1])$
\begin{equation*}
\alpha_{1} (\phi)
=
\operatorname*{ess sup}_{y \in [0,1]}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}
\lambda_i \,  \mu(E_i^y),
\quad
\alpha_{2} (\phi)
=
\operatorname*{ess sup}_{x \in [0,1]}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}
\lambda_i \,  \mu(E_i^x),
\end{equation*}
where $\mu$ is the measure on 
$[0,1]$,
then
$\Phi([0,1] \times [0,1]) \subset \mathcal{A}([0,1] \times [0,1])$.

Suppose 
$f^+ \in \mathcal{A}([0,1] \times [0,1])$,
$f^+(x,y) \geqslant 0$
for any
$x,y \in [0,1]$
and define
$$
\phi_m(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{k}{2^m},
&\text{if} \
\frac{k}{2^m} \leqslant f^+(x,y) <  \frac{k+1}{2^m}, \
k=0,1,\ldots, 2^{m}m - 1,
\\
m,
&\text{if} \
f^+(x,y) \geqslant m.
\end{cases}
$$
Then we have
$$
\forall m \in \mathbb{N}: \quad \phi_m \in \Phi([0,1] \times [0,1]),
$$$$\forall x,y \in [0,1]: \quad \phi_1(x,y) \leqslant \phi_2(x,y) \leqslant \ldots \leqslant f^+(x,y),
$$
and
\begin{equation*}
\forall x,y \in [0,1]: \quad f^+(x,y) = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \phi_m(x,y).
\end{equation*}

From conditions 
$\alpha_1(f^+) < \infty$
and
$\alpha_2(f^+) < \infty$
it follows that
for any fixed
$y \in [0,1]$
the function
$f^+(\cdot, y)$ is integrable
and for any fixed
$x \in [0,1]$
the function
$f^+(x, \cdot)$ is integrable too.
Hence, the dominated convergence theorem shows that the sequences of functions
\begin{equation*}
g^{1}_m(y) =
\int\limits_{0}^{1}
\left(
f^+(x, y) - \phi_m(x,y)
\right)
dx,
\quad
y \in [0,1],
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
g^{2}_m(x) =
\int\limits_{0}^{1}
\left(
f^+(x, y) - \phi_m(x,y)
\right)
dy,
\quad x \in [0,1],
\end{equation*}
converges to $0$ pointwise.
Now using Egorov's theorem we can conclude that the sequences
$g^{1}_m$ and $g^{2}_m$
converges to $0$ almost uniform but not uniform.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: just an idea to the first question: I would try to compare the norm in $\mathcal A([0,1]\times[0,1])$ and the $L_1$ norm in the same space to see if one is weaker/stronger than the other or not